# How to retrieve image from local database and display in ListView (Android)

Tags: android, listview

[]I have a local database that is created using SQLite Manager and what I wanted to do is retrieve the data(item name, price, and image) from the database and display in a listview. I stored the image in drawable folder(kids.jpg) and in database I stored the name of the picture as string(kids).

The content of the listview will keep changing base on the condition of query.

The problem I am facing now is I can retrieve the name, price, and even the name of the image and list it out in the listview, but I don't know how to display the image in the listview.

I know that below code can be used to call drawable image from string but how am I going to insert the code to the listview?

```
int Image = getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.user.birthdaygiftpredictor:drawable/" + Gimage, null, null);
            gift_image.setImageResource(Image);
```

Below is my code for SimpleCursorAdapter

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM gift WHERE "+strValue+" OR hobby LIKE '%"+hobby+"%' OR gift_price<='"+budget+"' ORDER BY gift_price ASC ;",null);

    String[] from = new String[] {
            cursor.getColumnName(0),
            cursor.getColumnName(1),
            cursor.getColumnName(2),
            cursor.getColumnName(4),
            cursor.getColumnName(4),
            cursor.getColumnName(5),
            cursor.getColumnName(10)

    };
    int[] to = new int[] {
            R.id.gift_id,
            R.id.gift_name,
            R.id.gift_price,
            R.id.gift_image,
            R.id.image,
            R.id.gift_description,
            R.id.link

    };

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            Result_1_match.this, R.layout.view_gift_list, cursor, from, to);

 adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder(){

    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){

        if(view.getId() == R.id.gift_image){ // your ImageView id in xml
            DbHelper2 connect = new DbHelper2(Result_1_match.this);
            connect.openDataBase();
            SQLiteDatabase db = connect.getWritableDatabase();
            List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("your query;", null);
            int i=0;
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                a.add(i,c.getString(0));
                i++;
            }
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.gift_image);
            int resID = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(cursor.getString(columnIndex), "drawable",  getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
            imageView.setImageResource(resID);

            return true; //true because the data was bound to the view
        }
        return false;
    }
});

 list.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.imageView3));
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Update: Finally I solved the problem and successfully listed out the image using Mukesh Rana concept. Above is the correct code. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the google documentation for `SimpleCursorAdapter`, it says

> SimpleCursorAdapter is an easy adapter to map columns from a cursor to
>   TextViews or ImageViews defined in an XML file. You can specify which
>   columns you want, which views you want to display the columns, and the
>   XML file that defines the appearance of these views. Binding occurs in
>   two phases. First, if a SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder is available,
>   setViewValue(android.view.View, android.database.Cursor, int) is
>   invoked. If the returned value is true, binding has occured. If the
>   returned value is false and the view to bind is a TextView,
>   setViewText(TextView, String) is invoked. If the returned value is
>   false and the view to bind is an ImageView, setViewImage(ImageView,
>   String) is invoked. If no appropriate binding can be found, an
>   IllegalStateException is thrown.

So you can easily override the corresponding `setViewText(TextView,String)` and `setViewImage(ImageView,String)` method. But If you still don't know how to do that , you can simply add a `ViewBinder` to your list adapter.

```
    adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder(){
   /** Binds the Cursor column defined by the specified index to the specified view */
   public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){
       if(view.getId() == R.id.your_image_view_id){ // your ImageView id in xml
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView) view;
                     int resID = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(cursor.getString(columnIndex), "drawable",  getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
                     imageView.setImageDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(resID));
           return true; //true because the data was bound to the view
       }
       return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: I have updated the code in the question by inserting the code you gave. Unfortunately the image is still unable to display. I run on debug mode and  I get 0 for resID. Can you please check my code again and correct me if I am wrong. Appreciate for your help.

Comment: what's the value for this cursor.getString(columnIndex) while debugging, is it the correct image name?

Comment: i get a value of 4 instead of image name

Comment: so in short you are not able to fetch the correct image name from database. Can you simply debug your cursor to check whether an image name is coming in the cursor or not and also the index for that image in your cursor?

Comment: If the result of the query have 5 records, which means that I have 5 items in the listview, so which image name should I get in debug mode?

Comment: how's your layout for each of the listview item? Does it contains both ListView and ImageView in each row?

Comment: the layout of this java (result_1_match.xml) contain only one listview. All the textview and imageview are in another xml (view_gift_list.xml)

Comment: is there any restriction to you that you only want to use CursorAdapter? or you can also use ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter? if it is a restriction, then can you simply let me know all the values you are getting in your cursor by debugging?

Comment: I tried to hardcode the image name to the listview and it works. But the problem now is if the result of the query has 10 records, how am I going to pass all the value to the viewBinder(String abc)? The latest code is updated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

For this you needs to create a custom adapter similar to this and set to your list view:

public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter{

```
private final Activity context;
private final String[] web;
private final Integer[] imageId;
public CustomList(Activity context,
String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
this.context = context;
this.web = web;
this.imageId = imageId;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true); TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);         

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
txtTitle.setText(web[position]);

imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
return rowView;
}
}
```

Complete implementation is available on this link:
http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html